# Will small random dynamic snippets break caching

Tags: cache

I am busy writing a WordPress plugin. Now most users have cache plugins installed, they cache the pages. I know also some webservers as nginx have php caching and whatnot. There are also things like memcached.

Now I have to admit I do not know exactly how they work, if anyone have some good links on how they work I would be glad. Some links where it's explained simple, not to technical.

Now the question. My plugin **displays different statistics** on posts, they are always different, will this break the caching of the page. To take is a step further, sometimes the statistics of the post needs updating, and there is a **small javascript snippet** added to the page.

Now will these two action result in the page not caching, or am I ok.

Comment: You may have better luck asking Wordpress questions on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had the question on there for a while, but I was redirected here. I guess I will close the question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have described I would be less worried about your plugin breaking caching and more worried about someones caching setup breaking your plugin, this isn't something you can control but it is something you can try and mitigate against by using the common best practices on plugin creation.

If you are worried about a specific caching plugin my suggestion would be to test it, it is the only way to know for sure.